# PHP copy() method doesn't work on server (NGINX)

Tags: php, image, nginx, server

I'm building a blog and I need to store images on my server. The images are given with full URL and when I post the article it saves the image with the copy() method.

In local all works well, but on my server nothing changes. However `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On` in php.ini file.

The strange thing is that the server changes the name of the file expected to be saved on, but it doesn't store it. For example I want to save this picture : `http://s.tfou.fr/mmdia/i/03/8/bob-l-eponge-10479038eajyx.png` . I put this URL inside my form, I submit it and then the server is saving this path : `content/images/563b62825ab53.png` as expected... But the path returns a 404 and the image is nowhere.

Here is my php code (cover is the name of the field where I put the image URL) :

```
$extension = explode('.', $_POST['cover']);
$uniq = uniqid();
$path = 'content/images/'.$uniq.'.'.$extension[count($extension)-1];
copy($_POST['cover'], $path);
$cover = $path;
```

here is what I have on the server with existing images pulled from my repo (from my local where all is working well) :

```
total 1328
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 105331 Nov  5 14:59 563b578484ea1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 311132 Nov  5 14:59 563b57cf1db89.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 132129 Nov  5 14:59 563b5a33d6c3b.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 180274 Nov  5 14:59 563b5bbfe649b.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 283665 Nov  5 14:59 563b5c068e0bf.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 311132 Nov  5 14:57 563b5fb480e73.png
```

But if I delete all and I try to make the server copy its own pictures, nothing appears... And here are the rights of the folders that contain the pictures :

```
drwxr-sr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Nov  5 14:57 content
```

which contains :

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Nov  5 14:59 images
```

which contains nothing...

I don't know if it's a server issue or a lack in my php.ini or something else.

Comment: you need to give write permission to the user/group  that nginx is running under (it shouldn't be root).  `chmod g+w images` should do what you want assuming nginx is running as group www-data on your system

Comment: I really don't think about this! Thanks a lot it works well now. Smart and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give write permission to the user/group that nginx is running under (it shouldn't be root). chmod g+w images should do what you want assuming nginx is running as group www-data on your system